# Нет перевода для сообщений Духа под неполным ответом

Tags: дефект, локализация, комментарии, ответы, дух-сообщества

Заметил что нет перевода для сообщений Духа для дополнения ответа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавил перевод:

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center. - [Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit], чтобы добавить информацию, например цитаты или документацию, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в справке] ($url$).](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16914)

Не знаю насколько корректно, если что можно подправить я думаю)

Comment: `[edit]` не нужно переводить, раз это ссылка, подпись к которой переведена отдельно. `в справочный центр` -> `в справке`

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, поправил, спасибо

Comment: [О важности пробелов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11743/176217). Точнее, их отсутствия :)