# Неправильное форматирование ссылки в комментарии Духа

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, комментарии, дух-сообщества

Пробел между скобками в конце сообщения приводит к неправильному отображению ссылки:

[image: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью...]

Неправильная строка: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16914

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11739/339283

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предложил новый [перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16914) [утверждён]:

> Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации.
> Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например,
> цитаты или документацию, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность
> вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как
> писать хорошие ответы [в Справке]($url$).

Comment: Утвердил. Неожиданно пробел затесался.